# Will a wifi repeater work with any standard?

Tags: wireless-networking

I need to set up a repeater to reach to the other end of my house. I'm looking at listings, and I see repeaters that work with the 802.11 **N** standard, and make no mention of another.

My wifi router uses the 802.11 **G** standard (it's a little old, but it works).

Will the repeater that supports wireless **N** work with the wireless **G** signal of my router?

Comment: I believe if you're trying to repeat a wireless signal wirelessly (vs running a cable to the repeater to extend your wireless network) the radios inside the devices must match. I know this is an issue with DD-WRT, not sure with commercial products. Anyone know for sure? It may be wise to choose a repeater that is the same brand as your router and check which devices the repeater supports specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

802.11n-supporting devices are supposed to be backwards-compatible with 802.11g and 802.11b, but it is possible to configure them in ways to refuse to work with older protocols. The default should be that it will support all previous protocols within the same frequency band, however.

The main thing you need to make sure of is that it's receiving/re-transmitting on 2.4 GHz band.

802.11n actually supports both 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz band. A device that fully supports the entire spectrum of 802.11n supports both frequency bands. A device that supports only 5 GHz would only be able to retransmit 5 GHz signals, which would be 802.11n or 802.11a. But if it supports 2.4 GHz then it should be able to work with 802.11g.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the transfer speed will be at the G standard (54mb/s) rather than N (144mb/s).